# How can I get the NYC taxi zone using a given coordinate?

Tags: dataset, socrata

`NYC Taxi trips dataset` in BigQuery has changed pickup and dropoff locations from the geographic positions(longitude and latitude) to the Taxi zone. I found [NYC Taxi Zones](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/755u-8jsi) but I'm struggling to get the zone from the given coordinates.

I think it is related to `multipolygon` but not sure. Does anyone can help me to provide a simple example to get the zone from a coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

Found [this link](https://medium.com/@linniartan/nyc-taxi-data-analysis-part-1-clean-and-transform-data-in-bigquery-2cb1142c6b8b) to figure out how.

```
/* find the boroughs and zone names for dropoff locations */
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` tz_do ON 
(ST_DWithin(tz_do.zone_geom,ST_GeogPoint(dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude), 0))
/* find the boroughs and zone names for pickup locations */
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` tz_pu ON 
(ST_DWithin(tz_pu.zone_geom,ST_GeogPoint(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude), 0))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).